# Connection error with Database in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am having problem in  laravel project connection with database on the live server all credentials are correct in .env and database.php files.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql.hostinger.in
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=u497405800_new
DB_USERNAME=u497405800_biosp
DB_PASSWORD=bn2OC9IzSop7
```

*ERROR SHOWING:*

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'u497405800_biosp'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO)

Comment: have you tried `DB_HOST=localhost` ?

Comment: yaa i have tried it

Comment: And are you sure `u497405800_biosp` user have proper rights to access database?

Comment: yaa i also checked it by accessing phpmyadmin using these credentials

Comment: Error message says `(using password: NO)` it's like you are trying to log in without password. Maybe you added it a few seconds later. Try to clear:cache and restart the app or apache/nginx

Comment: I am using correct password

Comment: You have maybe written the right password, but that error says that you are not trying to log in with a password. This can happen when you write the password in .env file and the app doesn't recognize the change. So try to restart everything for a test and maybe it will work.